# Using awk to count number of row range

Tags: awk

I have a data set: (file.txt)

```
X    Y
1    a
2    b
3    c
10   d
11   e
12   f
15   g
20   h     
25   i
30   j
35   k
40   l
41   m
42   n
43   o
46   p
```

I have two Up10 and Down10 columns,

- Up10: From (X) to (X-10) count of row.
- Down10 : From (X) to (X+10)
  count of row

For example:

```
X    Y    Up10    Down10    
35   k     3        5
```

- For Up10; 35-10 X=35 X=30 X=25 Total = 3 row
- For Down10; 35+10 X=35 X=40 X=41 X=42 X=42 Total = 5 row

I have tried, but i cant show 3rd and 4rth column:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
  NR==FNR{ 
   a[$1]+=$3
    next
  }
  { $(NF+10)=a[$3] }
   { $(NF-10)=a[$4] }
  1
' file.txt file.txt > file-2.txt
```

Desired Output:

```
X    Y    Up10    Down10
1    a     1        5
2    b     2        5
3    c     3        4
10   d     4        5
11   e     5        4
12   f     5        3
15   g     4        3
20   h     5        3
25   i     3        3
30   j     3        3
35   k     3        5
40   l     3        5
41   m     3        4
42   n     4        3
43   o     5        2
46   p     5        1
```

This is the Pierre François' solution: Thanks again @Pierre François

```
awk '
BEGIN{OFS="\t"; print "X\tY\tUp10\tDown10"}
(NR == FNR) && (FNR > 1){a[$1] = $1 + 0}
(NR > FNR) && (FNR > 1){ 
  up = 0; upl = $1 - 10
  down = 0; downl = $1 + 10
  for (i in a) { i += 0 # tricky: convert i to integer
    if ((i >= upl) && (i <= $1)) {up++}
    if ((i >= $1) && (i <= downl)) {down++}
  }
  print $1, $2, up, down;
}
' file.txt file.txt > file-2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in form of code in your question. Could you please do explain the Logic of getting expected output in your question, so that it becomes more clear to us, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting. For example:

`X    Y    Up10    Down10
    35   k     3        5 `

For Up10;
`35-10
X=35
X=30
X=25
Total = 3 row`

For Down10;
`35+10
X=35
X=40
X=41
X=42
X=42
Total = 5 row`

Comment: No, do not answer in comments, instead [edit] your question explaining what you mean with the two bullet points, they make little sense as of now.

Comment: Thanks for your warning @Quasimodo. I have edited my question.

Comment: Just when I was posting a working solution, the question has been closed. This is very frustrating. Send me a message if you want the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Pierre François' solution: Thanks again @Pierre François

```
awk '
BEGIN{OFS="\t"; print "X\tY\tUp10\tDown10"}
(NR == FNR) && (FNR > 1){a[$1] = $1 + 0}
(NR > FNR) && (FNR > 1){ 
  up = 0; upl = $1 - 10
  down = 0; downl = $1 + 10
  for (i in a) { i += 0 # tricky: convert i to integer
    if ((i >= upl) && (i <= $1)) {up++}
    if ((i >= $1) && (i <= downl)) {down++}
  }
  print $1, $2, up, down;
}
' file.txt file.txt > file-2.txt
```